# poorly sized square brackets due to equation over two lines -- how to equate their sizes?

Tags: align, typography, brackets

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M_3&=\frac{(\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k))\left(\sigma_1^2(k)+2\int_M D_1^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\right)}{2M_1}S_k^{*^2}\\[1ex]    &+\frac{(\mu(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k))\left(\sigma_2^2(k)+2\int_M D_2^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\right)}{2M_2}I_k^{*^2}\\[1ex]
&+\frac{2\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k)}{2\beta(k)(1-\rho(k))(1-\xi(k))}\left[\sigma_2^2(k)\right.\\
&\left.+2\int_M (D_2(k,y)-\log(1+D_2(k,y))\nu(dy)) \right]I_k^*
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to i get the `\left[` -- the "big" square bracket in line 3 -- to match the `\right]` big bracket in line 4?

Comment: don't use `\left\right` use `\bigl[` ... `\bigr]`   or whatever size you need (this will be a duplicate)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This gives me an error..

Comment: then you did something wrong. You probably left in `\right.` or some such

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the pairwise contents of the numerator terms of the three additive components of `M_3`, I would like to suggest you employ the `\splitdfrac` macro of the `mathtools` package for the numerator on line 3.

A separate issue: I think that the terms `S_k^{*^2}` and `I_k^{*^2}` in lines 1 and 2 are wrong, as the exponent `2` is too small. I believe `{S_k^*}^2` and `{I_k^*}^2` is better, as the exponent `2` will be rendered in `\scriptstyle` math mode instead of in `\scriptscriptstyle` math mode.

[image]

Note that there are no instances of `\left` and `\right` anywhere. That's quite deliberate.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{%amsfonts, %% amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb
      graphicx, verbatim,
      mathtools, % for '\splitdfrac' macro    
      amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,
      %amsmath %% amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools
      }
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M_3
&=\frac{\bigl[\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k)\bigr]
        \bigl[\sigma_1^2(k)+2\int_M D_1^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\bigr]}{%
        2M_1} \, {S_k^*}^2 \\[1ex]
&\quad+
  \frac{\bigl[\mu(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k)\bigr]
        \bigl[\sigma_2^2(k)+2\int_M D_2^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\bigr]}{%
        2M_2} \, {I_k^*}^2 \\[1ex]
&\quad+
  \frac{\splitdfrac{\bigl[2\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k)
            +\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k)\bigr]}
        {\cdot\bigl[\sigma_2^2(k) +2\int_M
            \bigl(D_2(k,y)-\log(1+D_2(k,y))\nu(dy) \bigr) \bigr]}}%
     {2\beta(k)(1-\rho(k))(1-\xi(k))} \, I_k^* \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice but don't you think it is a little confusing compared to what i tried? I'm no expert(you are!) but that's my two cents :) Also, unrelated to this question(actually somewhat it is), I had asked David if he could "fix" the mistakes in my thesis but unfortunately he couldn't do it! Maybe can you? I will pay for your time :)

Comment: @Math - I guess it really depends on what you're looking to emphasize to the reader. My solution brings out the overall structure -- e.g., three additive terms, the numerators of the additive terms consists of a product of two components -- quite forcefully, at the cost of making the reader slow down a bit to take in what the numerator of the third term is all about. Put differently, readers may have to slow down a bit, but I don't think that the choice of notation will confuse them.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll stick with your solution. So to my other question, would you be able to edit?

Answer (score 1):

`Mico` suggestion is the good one, but if you still want to use your coding as is, then try with the below:

**Using `left` and `right`**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M_3&=\frac{(\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k))\left(\sigma_1^2(k)+2\int_M D_1^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\right)}{2M_1}S_k^{*^2}\\[1ex]
&\quad +\frac{(\mu(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k))\left(\sigma_2^2(k)+2\int_M D_2^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\right)}{2M_2}I_k^{*^2}\\[1ex]
&\quad+\frac{2\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k)}{2\beta(k)(1-\rho(k))(1-\xi(k))}\left[\vphantom{+2\int_M (D_2(k,y)-\log(1+D_2(k,y))\nu(dy))}\sigma_2^2(k)\right.\\
&\quad\left.+2\int_M (D_2(k,y)-\log(1+D_2(k,y))\nu(dy)) \right]I_k^*
\end{align*}
```

**Using `biggl` and `biggr`**

```
\begin{align*}
M_3&=\frac{(\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k))\left(\sigma_1^2(k)+2\int_M D_1^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\right)}{2M_1}S_k^{*^2}\\[1ex]
&\quad +\frac{(\mu(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k))\left(\sigma_2^2(k)+2\int_M D_2^2(k,y)\nu(dy)\right)}{2M_2}I_k^{*^2}\\[1ex]
&\quad+\frac{2\mu(k)+\rho(k)+\xi(k)+\alpha(k)+\theta(k)+\gamma(k)}{2\beta(k)(1-\rho(k))(1-\xi(k))}\biggl[\sigma_2^2(k)\biggr.\\
&\quad\biggl.+2\int_M (D_2(k,y)-\log(1+D_2(k,y))\nu(dy)) \biggr]I_k^*
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You don't need `\biggr.` on line 3 or `\biggl.` on line 4. Furthermore, placing `\biggl[\sigma_2^2(k)` at the end of line 3 would appear to be inferior to placing it at the start of line 4..